# JSON.parse failed to parse stringified object string

Tags: javascript, json

I use

Before POST

```
const str = JSON.stringify(obj);
// The value of str is shown in the following image.
```

[image: str value]

After POST str to server and GET the data

```
const str2 = fetchStrFromServer();
// value of str2 is shown in the following image.

const obj2 = JSON.parse(str2);
```

[image: str2 value]

This will raise a unexpected token error.

I searched online and it appears to be the new line token needs to be escaped before post to server.

Are there any other characters needs to be escaped as well?
Are there any libraries that can do the escape stuff for this scenario?

note: all the images are screenshots in chrome console.

Comment: What exactly does the magic `fetchStrFromServer` function do? What does it return? What is the exact error message? Please read [ask] and [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly to provide relevant information.

Comment: Can you show us what exactly you're ending up passing to `JSON.parse`?

Comment: The `const` keyword prevents redeclaration of the same object. So if you ever declared `const obj = ...`, you can't redo it after if you are in the same scope. See here : https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/const

Comment: @Fefux your link appears to be broken but you're correct.

Comment: This is the good link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: Seeing the OP's edit and the error, I'm pretty sure that's not the issue here

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your server logic or the `fetchStrFromServer` function; can you show us that code?

Comment: After your edit, we need all the information asked in the first comment

Comment: if you are sending back data in JSON format from server it won't be parse again.